# How to connect android phone as portable device?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, usb-debugging, huawei

I always use usb cable to transfer data from my laptop(win 7 64 bit) to my android phone(huawei honor 4c) but recently after connecting my phone using usb cable phone isn't showing as a media device.But my phone is getting charge from PC.

Here's what I've done to fix the issue and none of them worked:

1. Restarted my phone.
2. Restarted my pc.
3. changed the cable
4. changed the pc.
5. Fatory Reset my phone.
6. usb debugging on/off
7. Tried different usb ports.

Here's a thing, that another phone is working properly as I wanted in my PC but my phone isn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can go into hisuite by connecting your phone up and then  selecting "connected as a media device" select that notification and then tapping "use as cd-rom" and then it should appear as a cd-rom drive and then install hisuite

Comment: after connecting usb cable hisuite in my pc shows device not connected

Answer (score -1):

If you have the Hisuite program built in your phone you can move files via that way.

Comment: sir previously I didn't have hisuite in my phone but uab debugging was just working fine.